# How to override this materialui style

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

This is css style which material-ui is having for a checkbox which i captured from console 
.MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary-262.MuiCheckbox-checked-260

When I tried to override this style is how i have tried overriding but it's not working

```
MuiCheckBox: {
    colorPrimary: {
      MuiCheckBox: {
        checked: {
          color:'#1565c0',
        }
      }
    }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to override the `checked` color of `Checkbox`. Have a look at overriding styles in material-ui [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes).

Documentation already provided an example of changing checkbox color. Have a look at this [example](https://material-ui.com/demos/selection-controls/).

Create `styles` and apply the styles to `Checkbox` using `classes` property.

```js
const styles={
  root:{
    '&$checked':{
      color: '#1565c0',
    }
  },
  checked:{}
}
```

```js
<Checkbox
          classes={{
                root:classes.root,
                checked:classes.checked}}
                {...props}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very useful link